# Using Chrome's Elasticsearch Head extension with SSL/https?

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Chrome's Elasticsearch Head plugin if the elasticsearch instance is using SSL/https for comms? I have not been able to find any information about it, and am guessing it isn't?

Comment: I only foud this commit with a message saying "merge latest elasticsearch-head commits; ES7 and X-pack support": https://github.com/TravisTX/elasticsearch-head-chrome/commit/e10ab7d5612750522012e080d49eb9b283123456 maybe you should give it a try? If not, here is the head as docker image: https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head

Comment: And here it says "es-head will attempt to remember the node that it connects to using html5 features, however this only works over http(s).", so it seems like there is ssl support: http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/

Comment: I think you are right, thanks!